# Convert NSArray containg NSDictionary objects into a single NSDictionary in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
NSArray *passenger = ({"seat_number" = "S4 , 54,PQ"; 
                       status = CNF;}
                      {"seat_number" = "S4 , 55,PQ"; 
                       status = CNF;})
```

Here is the array named "passenger".

Now I need to convert this array to dictionary.

I need all the `seat_number` key values in to one dictionary. but is it possible with the same key name

Can anybody tell me how?

Comment: you will have to tell us, how the dictionary should look like.

Comment: This is extremely ambiguous. If you gave us some code so that we can see exactly how you're receiving that information and storing it in an `NSArray`, that might help.

Comment: @vikingosegundo this is the array containing number of dictionaries.

Comment: sure. i know. but how do u want the result dictionary look like?

Comment: @vikingosegundo that is what my problem. I need all the `seat_number` key values in to one dictionary. but is it possible with the same key name.

Comment: so why dont you add that information to the question?

Comment: @vikingosegundo added that info to question. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: have that in mind: You will find a bunch of great developers on stack overflow — but not a single great mind reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED** It makes no sense to use a dictionary to hold multiple values for the same key, so you must use an array:

```
NSMutableArray *seatNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictonary *dict in passenger) {
    NSAssert([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]], @"That array contains more than just dictionaries...");
    NSString *seatNumber = [dict objectForKey:@"seat_number"];
    if (seatNumber)
        [seatNumbers insertObject:seatNumber];
}
```

Comment: Awesome; as -1 accepted answer.  Gotta love this site.

Comment: This was correct answer. My problem was solved. Thanq @trojanfoe